# Prime in substituted benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I was sent data for a molecule referred to as **1,2'-bis(4-aminophenoxy)benzene**. I haven't been able to figure out if that is a real molecule.

If I drop the prime, I know *1,2-bis(4-aminophenoxy)benzene* should look like that:

> [image: 1,2-bis(4-aminophenoxy)benzene]

and Google agrees. But with the prime, I have no idea what the molecule could be. Is there such a molecule, or is it a typo?

Comment: Your picture doesn't show 1,2-bis(4-aminophenoxy)benzene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the prime in the name, 1,2'-bis(4-aminophenoxy)benzene, is a typo as you originally suspected. However, the compound in your picture you thought is the correct one is neither 1,2-bis(4-aminophenoxy)benzene. The compound in the picture is 1,4-bis(4-aminophenoxy)benzene (CAS#: 3491-12-1).

Nonetheless, 1,2-bis(4-aminophenoxy)benzene exists (CAS#: 49860-97-1; Ref.1). It was synthesized and used to make *ortho*‐linked aromatic polyimides with aromatic dicarboxylic acids (Ref.1).

[image: 1,2-bis(4-aminophenoxy)benzene]

**Reference:**

1. Chin‐Ping Yang, Jeng‐Jieh Cherng, "Synthesis and properties of aromatic polyamides derived from 1,2‐bis(4‐aminophenoxy)benzene and aromatic dicarboxylic acids," *Polymer Chemistry* **1995**, *33(13)*, 2209-2220 (https://doi.org/10.1002/pola.1995.080331315).

Answer (score 7):

This is a typo. The prime 2' would refer to position 2 in a separate ring, but you are only numbering the central ring.

Note that you have drawn the structure of 1,4-bis(4-aminophenoxy)benzene.

You can test the names of chemicals and their structures using a tool such as [OPSIN](https://opsin.ch.cam.ac.uk/).